# find upper and lower bound value using binary search

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is the code for binary search, wondering if there is no match value, the question is the upper bound should be positioned at either small or small+1? And lower bound should be located at small or small-1, correct? Thanks.

```
def binary_search(my_list, key):
    assert my_list == sorted(my_list)

    large = len(my_list) -1
    small = 0

    while (small <= large):
        mid = (small + large) // 2 )
        # print small, mid, large, " - ", my_list[mid], "~", key
        if my_list[mid] < key:
            small = mid + 1
        elif my_list[mid] > key:
            large = mid - 1
        else:
            return mid

    raise ValueError
```

Comment: well... what's the question?

Comment: @Paul, thanks for the comments and I just edit my question to be more clear what I am asking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Paul is close, it should return `mid+1` for the upper value.  Instead of raising an exception, here is the code in Python that will return the lower and upper values:

```
value = my_list[mid]
lower = mid if value < key else mid-1
upper = mid if value > key else mid+1
return (lower, upper)
```

Here is an even simpler answer:

```
return (small-1, small)
```

Because `small` ends up above the `key`'s index when you're looking for it, the lower bound is `small-1` and the upper bound is `small`.

Comment: Brent, thanks a lot.  Wondering what is wrong with my methods? The upper bound should be positioned at either small or small+1, and lower bound should be located at small or small-1? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Brent, I think the value to be found could be larger than small in last step? Suppose in the last step, small and large and mid are equal and value > mid (or small or large), but value should be smaller than mid+1 since we move from mid+1? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: When `my_list[mid] < key: small = mid + 1`, then small is beyond the end of the list and that terminates the while loop.

Comment: Hi Brent, the idea of (small -1, small) is super smart and elegant, I like it. Mark as answered. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

That's not **that** simple. You'll have to take account of the fact, that the algorithm might either approximate the position of the searched item from the left (lower values) or right (higher values), which can't be determined after exiting the `while`-loop. Thus you'll have to check whether the value at `mid` is smaller or greater than the key:

```
lower = (my_list[mid] < key ? my_list[mid] : my_list[mid - 1]);
upper = (my_list[mid] > key ? my_list[mid] : my_list[mid + 1]);
```

Comment: Hi Paul, why not checking mid+1?

Comment: Oh, sry, i should've read the answer more carefully before posting it. I'll correct that

Comment: Hi Paul, then what is wrong with my methods? The upper bound should be positioned at either small or small+1, and lower bound should be located at small or small-1? Thanks.